# jquery .removeAttr and .remove('li')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery Sortable and I am taking a snap shot of the list so if the ajax update fails I can rollback.

When I capture the html on the start: it captures so added html and style sortable adds as it is being dragged. There is no beforeStart event in sortable so I have to mage do.

My solution is to remove the added html before I rollback.

My snapshot

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
  opacity: '0.5',
  start: function(event, ui) { 
    prevPositions = $(".sortable").html();
},
```

I get an added

```
<ul id="pageMenu" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked sortable ui-sortable">
    <li class="" id="item_3">
        <a href="/btstadmin/pages/view/3">Cover</a>
    </li>
    <li class="" id="item_4" style="width: 261px; height: 54px; position: absolute; opacity: 0.5; z-index: 1000;">
         <a href="/btstadmin/pages/view/4">keiths page1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-sortable-placeholder" style="visibility: hidden; height: 54px;"></li>
    <li class="" id="item_7">
        <a href="/btstadmin/pages/view/7">test page 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

On ajax error I have tried the .removeAttr

```
$(prevPositions).removeAttr( "style" );
$(".sortable").html(prevPositions).sortable("refreshPositions");
```

Comment: Why don't you change your logic around and only add the content if the AJAX request succeeds. That why there's no image or rollback. You simply display an error message and move on. Likewise, if it succeeds, add the new HTML and move on. Just a thought...

Comment: It is a sortable list that when the element is dropped in place the database get updated with the new order. If however the database update fails then the order on the screen is not correct and I need to go back to what the user had before they started to changed.